# Serving static content and handling 404 not found with Gorilla toolkit

Tags: go, gorilla

I recently asked about serving static content and handling 404 with Gorilla mux; when using Handle instead of PathPrefix, the app can serve the root page (http://localhost:8888):

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/myService", ServiceHandler)
    r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
    r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound)
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "8888")
    http.Serve(l, r)
}
```

However requests for pages within the root page (e.g. http://localhost:8888/demo/page1.html) get intercepted by the 404 handler. Is there any way to prevent this, while catching requests for non-existent pages or services? This is the directory structure:

```
...
main.go
static\
  | index.html
  demo\
    page1.html
    demo.js
    demo.css
    | jquery\
       | <js files>
    | images\
       | <png files>
```

Previous Question:

I am using the Gorilla mux toolkit to handle http requests in a web server app:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/myService", ServiceHandler)
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "8888")
    http.Serve(l, r)
}
```

I want to add a handler for invalid URLS, but it is never called:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/myService", ServiceHandler)
    r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound)
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "8888")
    http.Serve(l, r)
}
```

If I remove the static handler, the not found handler is called. However, the app needs to serve the static content, from a non-absolute path. Is there a way to combine that with 404 handling?

Comment: What is your directory structure ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler()` would match any path, making the `notfound` handler useless.

As mentioned in "[`route.go`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/8a875a034c69b940914d83ea03d3f1299b4d094b/route.go#L302-L303)":

```
// Note that it does not treat slashes specially 
// ("`/foobar/`" will be matched by the prefix "`/foo`") 
// so you may want to use a trailing slash here.
```

If you are using `PathPrefix` (as in [those tests](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/8096f47503459bcc74d1f4c487b7e6e42e5746b5/mux_test.go#L261)), use it for a specific path, not for the generic "`/`".

Comment: Thanks Von, I suspected that too. We want to serve a root index.html page, so entering "http://localhost:8888" in a browser gives the user the static content. Hence r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(). Is there an alternative to "/" that would permit 404 handling and serving the static content?

Comment: @CloomMagoo yes, but the side effect is that the `NotFoundHandler` would never be called.

Comment: @CloomMagoo for "/", use `mux.HandleFunc("/", ...)`, not `PathPrefix`

Comment: to use HandleFunc instead of PathPrefix, what would the actual handler func for serving the static directory look like? I'll investigate but if you have an example I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @CloomMagoo like any other httpHandler function.

Comment: mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(staticPath))) works, thanks. Now, requests for static content pages ("/content/page1") are getting intercepted by the NotFoundHandler. Still, progress.